# Employees Earning More Than any Managers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
| Id | Name  | Salary | ManagerId |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 3         |
| 2  | Henry | 80000  | 4         |
| 3  | Sam   | 60000  | NULL      |
| 4  | Max   | 90000  | NULL      |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
```

I need to get Employees earning more than any managers

I created a query that I get employees who earning more than THEIR managers:

```
select a.Name
from Employee a inner join Employee b on a.ManagerId = b.Id
where a.Salary > b.Salary
```

How I can modify this query for get more than ANY managers?

Comment: Use a `cross join` to produce a Cartesian product, that is then limited with the same where clause. `cross join Employee b where a.Salary > b.Salary`. You probably do NOT want to return the `MangerId` though, and instead return a distinct list of the employees that make more than any single manager...but if you do, this is how you'd return those.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any joining for this. Get the max salary of all managers and check that the employee salary is greater than the max manager salary

```
select a.Name
from Employee a 
where a.Salary > 
(SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee m WHERE m.id IN (SELECT managerID FROM Employee))--or however you determine managers
```

Comment: This is what I was about to suggest as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT E.[Name]
FROM dbo.Employee E
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.Employee E2
                   JOIN dbo.Employee M ON E2.ManagerID = M.id
              WHERE M.Salary < E.Salary);
```

The `EXISTS` is a little messy though, as the only way to tell if someone is a manager is if someone has them as their manager.

Answer (score 0):

> for get more than ANY managers

means that you want employees earning more than the **minimum** salary of the managers:

```
select name from employees 
where salary > ( 
  select min(salary) from employees
  where id in (select distinct managerid from employees)
)
```

or

```
select name from employees 
where salary > ANY ( 
  select salary from employees
  where id in (select distinct managerid from employees)
)
```

If you want only employees that are not managers use a CTE:

```
with cte as (select distinct managerid from employees)
select name from employees 
where 
  id not in cte
  and 
  salary > (select min(salary) from employees where id in cte)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a join instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name
FROM Employee a
CROSS JOIN Employee b 
WHERE a.Salary > b.Salary and b.Manager ID IS NULL
```